# OMA DRM v1 & v2 support on Android

Tags: android

Are [OMA DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_DRM) v1 and v2 supported on Android?

If no, is it planned?

is there any third party library that implements OMA DRAM v1 & v2?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it doesn't exist, but it looks like there are 3rd-party libraries.

From [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/6609e59ff09c1a58):

> Only forward lock is supported. We
>   don't have any plans to include an OMA
>   DRM2 solution as part of open source.
>   Packet Video has solutions available
>   for license, and I imagine that other
>   companies will also offers solutions
>   in the future.

It looks like he's talking about [Packet Video's core](http://www.packetvideo.com/products/core/technology.html). I don't know any more about it than that page tells us though.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking at the same question, and on the web I found:

http://www.discretix.com/PDF/Discretix_DRM.pdf 
and
http://www.irdeto.com/documents/HL_CW_OMA_DRM_Android_EN_H.pdf

which says to support Android. But I have no experience with it myself.

Comment: any experience with any DRM on android ?