# Android :: DRM for video content

Tags: android, drm

did not want to revive an old thread.
[OMA DRM v1 & v2 support on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244886/oma-drm-v1-v2-support-on-android)

we are trying to implement a DRM solution for video content for both streaming and offline. And have searched both high and low, these where are the few which repeats itself every time.

- http://www.irdeto.com/documents/HL_CW_OMA_DRM_Android_EN_H.pdf
- http://www.discretix.com/Android_Security.html
- http://www.haihaisoft.com/customize_android_media_player.aspx
- http://www.authentec.com/a/Production/Home.aspx

we are targeting phones & tabs
so android 3.0 can be helpful, went through the sdk docs, still couldn't make out how to use them.

also read somewhere android 2.4 (for phones) will support the DRM framework, in the meantime the market we are targeting may not upgrade to android 2.4 so soon. this requires us to find some custom implementation.

have been hitting the wall on all sides. please give your invaluable insights.
if i have missed something very obvious, correct me as well.

Comment: This is really not clear what your are asking

Comment: how to protect video (Streaming / Downloaded) in android < 3

Comment: check this article which i wrote recently : http://aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/  it explains in details about how to achieve multi-drm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security through obscurity.  It's the only way that DRM *can* work on a device owned by someone else.  Obsfucate your code and require updates to the latest version, which changes every week.

It's like putting a lock on a box, then putting the key in the lock, and hoping that no one finds the lock and key.  The solution is to change the location of the lock and key every few days, so that the vast majority of users can't be bothered to find it themselves or even to get the latest "crack".

Comment: "Security through obscurity" is the route, we have as a fallback for streaming content(SSL + POST). but for downloaded video file, couldn't find any alternatives.

Comment: @Sam - there's really no way to do it.  If a user is authorized to view it once, he can simply record the output from his sound and video cards.  You can protect media from mass piracy for maybe a week, or a month if it's not as popular.  From then on the DRM is ineffective.

Comment: i knew it in my heart, but had to do this as a profession, if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread -- but you may want to look at Adobe Access as well (http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/adobeaccess/). Supports Android with both streaming and offline possible.